# How can my website's security be compromised, if I implement prepared statements, sanitize user input and never use exec(), eval(), etc.?

Tags: php, security

What other exploits can be used with malicious intentions?

Comment: CSRF attack, is also one of basic attacks.

Comment: Some scholars closed this question,... huh

Comment: i wonder why it was close .. it a valid question ... eg. most people don't know how dangerous `include` is  ...... imageing `include($_GET['component'])` ???

Comment: Why this question was closed? It does points out valid concerns for newbie programmers. Geez.

Answer (score 1):

You also need to escape output, implement good session security (assuming an auth system) and secure your server (ftp / ssh / http of system files etc)